# Confusion about composing indexed lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I can create an `IndexedTraversal` for lists with a constant index like so:

```
constIndexedList :: i -> Lens.AnIndexedTraversal i [a] [b] a b
constIndexedList _ _ [] = pure []
constIndexedList index f (x:xs) = (:) <$> Lens.indexed f index x <*> constListIndex index f xs
```

I'd rather create it by composing two simpler lens:

```
constIndex :: i -> Lens.AnIndexedLens i a b a b
constIndex index f = Lens.indexed f index

constIndexedList :: i -> Lens.AnIndexedTraversal i [a] [b] a b
constIndexedList index = Lens.cloneLens (constIndex index) <. traverse
```

However this fails to type-check, and the type errors from `lens` are not ones that I easily understand:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Lens.Indexed
                         i (t0 a) (Lens.Bazaar (Lens.Indexed i) a b (t0 b))’
                 with ‘[a] -> Lens.Bazaar (Lens.Indexed i) a b [b]’
  Expected type: Lens.Indexed
                   i (t0 a) (Lens.Bazaar (Lens.Indexed i) a b (t0 b))
                 -> [a] -> Lens.Bazaar (Lens.Indexed i) a b [b]
    Actual type: ([a] -> Lens.Bazaar (Lens.Indexed i) a b [b])
                 -> [a] -> Lens.Bazaar (Lens.Indexed i) a b [b]
• In the first argument of ‘(<.)’, namely
    ‘Lens.cloneLens (constIndex index)’
  In the expression: Lens.cloneLens (constIndex index) <. traverse
```

Why can't I compose indexed lens like so?

I ended up finding a different modular way to do it (`Lens.reindexed (const index) Lens.traversed`, but I still wonder why the method mentioned above doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(<.)` expects an indexed optic on its left, but `cloneLens` gives it an unindexed lens.

One partial fix is to use `Lens.cloneIndexedLens` instead of `cloneLens`.

However, `A_`/`An_` variants of optics (`AnIndexedLens`) are meant to be argument types, not result types, which can use regular optics (`IndexedLens`). With that, `cloneIndexedLens` becomes unnecessary.

```
constIndex :: i -> Lens.IndexedLens i a b a b
constIndex i f = Lens.indexed f i

constIndexedList :: i -> Lens.IndexedTraversal i [a] [b] a b
constIndexedList i = constIndex i <. traverse
```

---

Monomorphic inputs and polymorphic outputs improve composability.

`IndexedLens` is a polymorphic type (notice the `forall` keyword in the type definition).

```
type IndexedLens i s t a b = forall f p. (Indexable i p, Functor f) => p a (f b) -> s -> f t
```

`AnIndexedLens` is monomorphic.

```
type AnIndexedLens i s t a b = Optical (Indexed i) (->) (Pretext (Indexed i) a b) s t a b
```

Every `IndexedLens` is `AnIndexedLens`, but the conversion the other way must go through an explicit `cloneIndexedLens`.